# Saving PFFile into Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, parse-platform, nsdata

I have a local database implemented in my iOS app using Core Data that is populated from a backend driven by Parse.

I want to have a Core Data entity that has as an attribute a `PFFile` (a parse file object). Core Data doesn't support `PFFile`s but it does support `NSData`.

How could I get a `NSData` representation of my `PFFile`?

Answer (score 1):

Call `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:` on the file.

Note that storing the data on disk and storing the path you saved it at is usually a better idea than storing the data in Core Data.